# How does Google get 3d video to play in iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, video, safari, 3d, virtual-reality

I didn't think this was possible, but if you go to this site:

https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com

The 3D video elements clearly work on my iPhone 7 running iOS 10 Safari... I also tested it on an iPhone 6 running iOS 9 and it works there too.  How are they accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "360"/"spherical", not "3d"? I don't see 3d video at that site on Safari on iOS 10 on my iPhone 6S.